# developing Office Add-in on a Mac and loading "https://localhost:3000/manifest.xml"

Tags: macos, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I am trying to develop an Office Add-In for Word on a MacBook. When I try to sideload the web word application the installation of the Add-In fails, because it cannot load the XML file from https://localhost:3000/manifest.xml.

The certicate is installed fine, and running:
`npx office-addin-dev-certs verify`

is showing this.

`You have trusted access to https://localhost. Certificate: /Users/geraldfuchs/.office-addin-dev-certs/localhost.crt Key: /Users/geraldfuchs/.office-addin-dev-certs/localhost.key`

but when the addin starts it shows this error:
**Cannot access manifest url at https://127.0.0.1:3000/manifest.xml. Please ensure the URL is accessable**

Did anyone succeed in using the Web Sideload?

I tried to sideload the web applocation to test office-addin

Comment: Are you able to access the mentioned URL in any web browser? Do you get any errors in that case?

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue (access to port 3000)?